# Movable image according to some values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a speedometer, like the following, for my website where the speed changes according to some values I give it to.

I was thinking of having a background image with values from 0-80 and have a different image on top of that which will act as the needle of the speedometer and will move accordingly on top of the corresponding speeds.

can you point me to any plugin or any hint or way so that I can I achieve this behavior?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Highchart:http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer   Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-speedometer/

Comment: easy to implement https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge